# export 'ɵɵelementHostStyling' was not found in '@angular/core' Angular v8.1.0

Tags: angular, npm

**prerequisite**

I have just updated my application to the following packages

```
"@angular/cdk": "^8.0.2",
"@angular/common": "~8.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.0.3",
"@angular/core": "^8.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "^8.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^8.1.0",
"@angular/router": "^8.1.0",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.800.6",
"@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.800.6",
"@angular/animations": "^8.1.0",
"@angular/cli": "^8.1.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.1.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^8.1.0"
```

**the compilation fails**

I have runned my command `npm run watch` and the following errors occur

```
"build-libs": "npm run build-helper-messages && npm run build-kpi-mrr && npm run build-kpi",
"watch": "npm run build-libs &&  ng serve --watch --open --ssl true"
```

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/common.js 4031:8-28
> "export 'ɵɵelementHostStyling' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> ERROR
> in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/common.js 5468:8-28 "export
> 'ɵɵelementHostStyling' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/common.js 4035:8-33 "export
> 'ɵɵelementHostStylingApply' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/common.js 5472:8-33 "export
> 'ɵɵelementHostStylingApply' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/common.js 4034:8-31 "export
> 'ɵɵelementHostStylingMap' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/common.js 5471:8-31 "export
> 'ɵɵelementHostStylingMap' was not found in '@angular/core'

**do you have any idea how to correct the issue?**

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30413#issuecomment-500688551)?

Comment: @DafangCao I didn't try before testing the answer here below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should update all angular dependencies, probably problem is one of angular dependencies and some of them are up to date and some of them are still angular 8 but not latest, so run this command and this should fix the problem :

```
ng update --all --force
```

Also before running above command try to remove `node_modules` and then `npm install`

You probably didn't have latest version of this library

```
@angular/material 
@angular/cdk
@angular/animations 
@angular/core
```

This worked for me, also if you have any problems read this angular issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30413